# How do you add primary keys in a Django URL?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am making a blog and I want to go to a specific blog post by clicking on a button. I know I need to use a primary key in the URL, but what is the syntax? And how can I implement it?

Comment: `path("your-url/prefix/<pk:int>", your_view_name)` in urls.py and in views access pk as `def view_name(request, pk):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some syntax for when you want to use a URL to go to a particular model's instance. You can tweak it for your needs, eg the "int:pk" and the kwargs={"pk": self.pk}.

In your app's urls.py, add

path('mypage/int:pk/',views.myPageDetail.as_view(),name='mypage_detail'),

in your models.py class based Model, add a function to your model

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("mypage_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```